# cdi bean lack of value when accessed through public field

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, quarkus

I have a configuration class, which I inject into another class.

Configuration class looks as follows:

```
@RequestScoped
public class Configuration {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "VALUE")
    public String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This configuration is injected into the following place:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EndpointImpl implements Endpoint {

    private Configuration configuration;

    @Inject
    public EndpointImpl(Configuration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        System.out.println("configuration.value=" + configuration.value);
        System.out.println("configuration.getValue()=" + configuration.getValue());
        System.out.println("configuration.value=" + configuration.value);
    }
```

Logs printed after going through constructor:

> configuration.value=null
>
> configuration.getValue()=someValue
>
> configuration.value=null

I added postConstructor with the below similar code:

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(){
    System.out.println("configuration.value="+configuration.value);
    System.out.println("configuration.getValue()="+configuration.getValue());
    System.out.println("configuration.value="+configuration.value);
}
```

and the result is the same.

Everything works fine as long as the value is retrieved through the getter method. When I try to retrieve it through the public field it returns null. I thought that, when CDI completes the process of building the bean, the fields inside the class will be set to appropriate values.

Why does it behave in such a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected, because your `Configuration` bean is `@RequestScoped`. The request scope is one of so-called *normal scopes*, and whenever you `@Inject` a normal-scoped bean, you will always get a so-called *client proxy*.

The client proxy exists to lookup the correct bean instance and forward method invocations to it. In this case, it will lookup the bean instance for *current request*.

So, when you're accessing fields, you're accessing them on the client proxy -- not on the instance that pertains to the current request.

Whenever you inject a normal-scoped bean, never access fields directly. Always call methods. You may access fields directly on `@Singleton` and `@Dependent` beans, because they don't come up with a client proxy.

Comment: This is correct, I'd only add that the `@Singleton` is meant as CDI singleton (`jakarta.inject.Singleton`) and *not* the EJB one.

Comment: These proxies are needed for RequestScoped bean, because it allows to share one instance of bean across many injection points. The Dependent bean will be instantiated for each injection point independent. Is this a point ?

Comment: Quarkus doesn't support EJB, so it's unlikely anyone would add the EJB `@Singleton`, but good point. And yes, the proxy is needed -- but it won't _share one instance across many injection points_. If that's what you need, then `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Singleton` is a good choice. What `@RequestScoped` does is that it provides one instance of the bean __for each request__ (the definition of request is pretty wide, but you may think "HTTP request" for example). Without injecting a proxy, it wouldn't be possible to dispatch method calls to the correct "current" instance of the bean.